# How to have the access token to access firebase rest api?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the access token to access FIREBASE REST API. According to this link: [Authenticate REST Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) I downloaded service account key file. Then I pasted it into app directory of an android project.

[image]

But every time it gets null in FileInputStream. The rest of the java code down below:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
try {
    serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("pooka-166905-firebase-adminsdk-fmil7-99eadf997d.json");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

GoogleCredential googleCred = null;
try {
    googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(serviceAccount);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

GoogleCredential scoped = googleCred.createScoped(
        Arrays.asList(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        )
);

try {
    scoped.refreshToken();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String token = scoped.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Did you try clean build ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it did not work.